# jQuery addClass on user control list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list on a user control and a jquery script that works when an li is clicked.  This works fine.  I want to change the class on the selected li but having trouble making this work. I tried this in a fiddle and no problem - but in my actual page - no good.

the fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/u6sykb8d/7/

the actual jquery script is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.listButtons li').on("click", function () {
        $('.selected').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        var tabid = $(this).attr('id');
        var cont = $(this).closest($(".container"));

        var tabs = ["tabAddress", "tabPeople0", "tabPeople1", "tabPeople2", "tabPeople3", "tabPeople4"];
        var divs = ["divAddress0", "divPeople_0", "divPeople_1", "divPeople_2", "divPeople_3", "divPeople_4"];
        var indx = tabs.indexOf(tabid);
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            if (i == indx) {
                cont.find($("div[id$='" + divs[i] + "']")).show();
            }
            else {
                cont.find($("div[id$='" + divs[i] + "']")).hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

the rest of the script works, the lines removing and adding the class don't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: As the code snippet you provided does not allow for the error to be reproduced we will need to see the additional code on the page in-order to replicate the error and provide a solution.

Comment: What do you mean: "I want to change the class on the selected li" and if this works on fiddle, we need to see your page.

Comment: Do you add and remove buttons dynamically?

Comment: the code for the page is too large to add completely, let me see if I can isolate the part that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

embarrassed to say but after digging through the code the problem turned out to be an extra space in the css file 'li .selected' instead of 'li.selected' . Thanks for the help